# SMTP gmail fails on connect C#

Tags: c#, gmail

I have this code:

```cs
var emailToSend = new MimeMessage();
emailToSend.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("myemail@gmail.com"));
emailToSend.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(email));
emailToSend.Subject = subject;
emailToSend.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
{
    Text = htmlMessage
};
using (var emailClient = new SmtpClient())
{
    emailClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587,
        MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    emailClient.Authenticate("myemail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
    emailClient.SendAsync(emailToSend);
    emailClient.Disconnect(true);
}

return Task.CompletedTask;
```

In debugging, it stucks at emailClient.connect and after a few moments trows error:

> SmtpCommandException: 5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor q27-20020ac2515b000000b004efe8174586sm2102062lfd.126 - gsmtp

What is a specific password and how do I set it?

Comment: Did you check the link?

Comment: Yes, posted without checking, it was different steps but you need to go to Google ->Accounts two steps authentication, and at the bottom you can create a password for the app. It works, sorry for wasting anyone's time.

Comment: No waste of time.  I do recall google going for mfa for everything..   just don't remember when.